# How to get complete path or URL of a File in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am uploading bulk files using Dropbox .NET API.

I want that after uploading the file how to get a complete path or URL like - "https://www.dropbox.com/work/Apps/*****/testinng234/1.mp3". So that I can able to use this link directly. 

Please suggest me the best way and share some code.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/How-to-get-complete-path-or-URL-of-a-File/m-p/329365 ]

Comment: @Greg Thanks !!